# Export all imported interfaces

Tags: typescript

I am writing a NPM package which offers a class. In this class I am using multiple interfaces which I have defined in a "types.ts" file. Unfortunately I am not able to access these interfaces when I want to use the package myself. I assume it is because I need to export the imported interfaces. After researching a bit I noticed there is `export import { IMyInterface } from './common/types'`, but it seems that is outdated/deprecated.

**My index.ts:**

```
import { IMyInterface, IMyInterface2 } from './common/types';

export class ExampleClass {
  public async getInfo(): Promise<IMyInterface[]> {
    return await request();
  }
}
```

So when I use this library I do see the returned Type in VSCode, but I can not define variables using these types. For instance this doesn't work as `IMyInterface` can not be found:

```
import { ExampleClass } from 'my-library'
const instance = new ExampleClass();
const info: IMyInterface = instance.getInfo();
```

**My question:**

How can I make my library's interfaces public for others who import the Class?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-export your interfaces in your exampleClass file. [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

search for re-exports.

```
export {IMyInterface as exampleInterface} from "./common/types";
export {IMyInterface2 as exampleInterface2} from "./common/types";
```

After you can just import new example interfaces where you need to use them.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to avoid. It seems if there is no better way the `export import` method was way better. Why would they deprecate that then? The problem with your approach is that I need to add every interface I import to the export list.

Comment: If you want to export all interfaces you can do that by typing "*" instead of interface name. I'm assuming you want to expose everything in types.

Comment: Ideally I would only export those interfaces which I have also imported from `types`.